# python duplicate function parameter and execution

Tags: python

Help
i have the following code.

I ran `gspread_connect()` and no issue found.
The problem is I don't want to execute `get_data_gsheet()` by supplying the parameters that required by `gspread_connect()` in

`gc = gspread_connect(config_section_name,config_section_var,debug_mode=debug_mode)`

from the following code:

```
def gspread_connect(config_section_name,config_section_var,debug_mode=False):
    gc = None
#     json_key = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())+'\\keyz\gsheet-automations-383508-f832c5a2f142.json'
    json_key = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'creds'),get_config_value(config_section_name,config_section_var))
    print_text_line(1,"json key: {} is exist? {}".format(json_key,os.path.exists(json_key)),debug_mode)    
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    if os.path.exists(json_key):
        print_text_line(1,"json key exists. Creating credentials...")
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_key, scope)
        print_text_line(1,"credentials created. Authorizing GSpread...")
        try:
            gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
            print('Gspread authorized')
        except Exception as e:
            print_text_line(1,"Authorization with gspread failed.\n{}".format(e))
    else:
        print_text_line(1,'Failed to get credentials. Key is not found.\nLocation: {}'.format(json_key))
    return gc

def get_data_gsheet(file_id,worksheet_name,debug_mode=False):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    try:
        gc = gspread_connect(config_section_name,config_section_var,debug_mode=debug_mode)
        sh = gc.open_by_key(file_id)
        try:
            ws = sh.worksheet(worksheet_name)
            print_text_line(1,"Getting data from '{}' in '{}'...".format(worksheet_name,file_id),debug_mode)
            data = ws.get_all_records()
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            print("Getting data completed.\n Total row: {} row(s)".format(df.shape[0]))
            print_text_line(1,"Sample data:\n{}".format(df.head()),debug_mode)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to get data from '{}'".format(worksheet_name))
            print(e)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to connect with file_id '{}'".format(file_id))
        print(e)
    return df
```

how do I do that?

Comment: you need to somehow get values for `config_section_name, config_section_var` , that's obvious. If you don't want to pass them as args for `get_data_gsheet`, you need to inject them by calling some other global function(s) within

Comment: maybe make them required input arguments from main function

Comment: You could assign them to global variables, but that's generally poor design. Why don't you want to pass them as parameters?

Comment: hi @Barmar. If i have to pass them as parameters, then it would be the following functions:

`def get_data_gsheet(config_section_name, config_section_var, file_id,worksheet_name,debug_mode=False)`

`def update_data_gsheet(config_section_name, config_section_var, file_id,worksheet_name,df,debug_mode=False)`

they have duplicate params.  I don't know if this is a good design.
I want to avoid poor design and repetitive functions/parameter

Comment: I thought you were talking about the functions as you already defined them, not adding additional parameters.

Comment: If you have additional arguments that should just be passed along to another function without interpretation, use `*args` or `**kwargs`.